# Insert file into google drive with Web request

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, google-drive-api

I'm trying to insert a file in google drive using webRequest (since I'm implementing an resumable async upload), but I have no idea how to put data in request "body".

From now, I have:

```
    public static HttpWebRequest CreateUploadRequest(Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService driveService, string uri, Stream contentStream, string title, string mimeType, string description = null)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

        request.Method = "PUT";

        Dictionary<string, object> requestBody = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        requestBody["title"] = title;
        requestBody["mimeType"] = mimeType;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description))
        {
            requestBody["description"] = description;
        }

        driveService.Authenticator.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(request);


        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        //How to do that???

        requestStream.Close();

        return request;
    }
```

I set the headers for the HttpWebRequest, how the data of the body should be disposed?
And whats is the property name for the byte[] data of the file to be inserted?

Any example whould be appreciated.

Comment: was there a solution ? did you find any ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDK documentation on [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#simple) page says:

> The body of the request is formatted as a multipart/related content type RFC2387 and contains exactly two parts. The parts are identified by a boundary string, and the final boundary string is followed by two hyphens.

If you've never worked with it, [RFC2387](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2387) is the MIME definition. Binary data in MIME is typically BASE64 encoded, like in this example from the RFC:

```
 Content-Type: Application/octet-stream
 Content-Description: The fixed length records
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
 Content-ID: <950120.aaCB@XIson.com>

 T2xkIE1hY0RvbmFsZCBoYWQgYSBmYXJtCkUgSS
 BFIEkgTwpBbmQgb24gaGlzIGZhcm0gaGUgaGFk
 IHNvbWUgZHVja3MKRSBJIEUgSSBPCldpdGggYS
 BxdWFjayBxdWFjayBoZXJlLAphIHF1YWNrIHF1
 YWNrIHRoZXJlLApldmVyeSB3aGVyZSBhIHF1YW
 NrIHF1YWNrCkUgSSBFIEkgTwo=
```

Have a look at this question for an example of uploading binary data to a Web request: [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)